# Google Map API showing a error "google is not defined" on console

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API to display maps on my website. Most of the time, it works fine, but occasionally, I encounter the following error in the browser console. I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue. This issue mostly happens when the first page loads.

Here is the error displayed in the console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
at render_map (_main.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (_main.js:10)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (_main.js:10)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)

Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error: NoApiKeys  Warning

The script element that loads the API has no API key. Please make sure you include a valid API key as a key parameter. You can generate a new API key on the Google API Console.

have a look at this link for error messages
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

Comment: We put in the API key, and it works on and off. If it were only an API problem, it wouldn't work sometimes.